# comparing more than one dict in python to get the maximum value for similar key

Tags: python, dictionary, max

Hello Everyone,

I am struck in while solving the below question i.e **comparing more than one dict in python to get the maximum value for similar key**.Could you please help me to solve this type of question.

Note: Similar kind of question was asked in Stackoverflow but that is only for two dictionaries with all have same size but in my question it is quiet different.

Sample Input:

```py
a={"test1":90,  "test2":45,  "test4":74}

b={"test1":32,  "test2":45,  "test3":82,  "test5":100}

c={"test1":78,  "test2":65,  "test3":92,  "test4":90,  "test5":90}

d={"test1":42,  "test2":35,  "test3":62,  "test4":80}
```

Sample Output:

```py
res={"test1":90,  "test2":65,  "test3":92,  "test4":90,   "test5":100}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```py
dicts = [a,b,c,d]
res ={}
for dic in dicts:
    for key in dic.keys():
        if key not in res.keys():
            res[key] = dic[key]
        if dic[key] > res[key]:
            res[key] = dic[key]
```